# Rails model belongs to parent model through many models in the middle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

[image]

I have the shown relationship between models. The problem is, the model Formulari can belong to a Topic, or to an Area, or to a Thema, or to Subthema. That's why I use the optional: true

```
class Formulari < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :topic, optional: true
  belongs_to :area, optional: true
  belongs_to :thema, optional: true
  belongs_to :subthema, optional: true

  ### how to make this work?
  ### it just uses the last one
  has_one :user, through: :area
  has_one :user, through: :thema
end
```

I want to access @formulari.user, so I need to use the has_one through relationship, but since I have for path options, it's tricky. If I write more than one has_one through relationships, rails just takes one of them.

I don't know how to tell rails, multiple has_one through relationships to a model.

Any help would be appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: I think you can make use of self-referential model here with the parent-child relationship

Comment: Check this http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use ActiveRecord's polymorphic association like following for example

```
class Formulari < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :formularable, polymorphic: true

  has_one :user
end
```

then other models would have

```
class Areas
   has_many :formulari, as: :formularable
end
```

And the other two models as well. And yes - why not add `user_id` and `topic_id` straight to `Formulari`. This will only need more logic to assign and reassign them when updating. In my opinion it is less frustrating than for example requesting user from `subthema` all way long(using long joins or long chain requests resulting in slow DB response).

If you end up using polymorphic then to correctly add columns [read this doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)
Don't hesitate to ask questions if you meet any problems, but I encourage you to read documentation or watch railscasts for example.

Comment: thanks a lot, yeah it should work. A friend told me this approach, but I wanted to see if I could solve the problem without any advanced stuff like polymorphic.